# Nesting variables in grafana

Tags: grafana, dashboard

Say I create a custom variable `v1` having values `x,y,z` and now I create a new variable `v2` and want to use v1 in it. i.e, I want to define v2 to be a custom variable with values x-1, y-1, z-1 where x,y,z are the values of v1.
How do I go about with this? I have tried using the ${v1} syntax but to no avail. This works outside the variables page in say a panel, but how do I make a variable change its value based on another variable.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that custom variables cannot be chained with the current setup of grafana. Chaining is only supported through datasource queries.